# I have made a software application in Java.I want to apply a windows shortcut key to it

Tags: java, windows

I have made a software application in Java.I want to apply a windows shortcut key to itSo that the Users does not double click it every time.How can I Do That..?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the icon of your program and choose properties.
In the "connection"-tab is a shortcut-field where you can apply any shortcut to your program.

My Windows is german, so it might not be the words "properties" or "connection" exactly ;)

But I don't tink that there is a way to give your program a shortcut by programming it into it.

Comment: In English, it's the "Shortcut" tab.